# Crear una variable string con varios párrafos

Tags: javascript

quisera consultar con la posibilidad de crear una variable string con varios párrafos:

```
var comentario = "Primer párrafo.

                  Segundo párrafo.

                  Último párrafo";
```

¿Es posible crear un string con varios párrafos para despues mostrarlo en un elemento HTML?

O debo crear la variable:

```
var comentario = "<p>Primer párrafo.</p>

                  <p>Segundo párrafo.</p>

                  <p>Último párrafo.</p>"
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: A que te refieres con consultar?

Comment: A que tengo una pregunta.

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer si se puede, puedes tener una variable que contenga varios parrafos y despues pones la variable como tal en un <div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toma la cadena original, separa por saltos de línea y formatea como párrafos antes de asignar como HTML:

```js
var comentario = `Primer párrafo.

                  Segundo párrafo.

                  Último párrafo`;

function crearParrafos(texto) {
    // Inicializar salida
    let html = '';
    // Separar párrafos por saltos de línea
    let ps = texto.split("\n");
    // Recorrer cada párrafo
    ps.forEach(p => {
        // Eliminar espacios
        p = p.trim();
        // Solo si el párrafo no está vacío
        if(p != '') {
            // Agregar a salida
            html += `<p>${p}</p>`;
        }
    });
    // Devolver salida
    return html;
}

// Ejecutar función
let resultado = crearParrafos(comentario);
// Mostrar resultado en consola
console.log(resultado);
// Asignar HTML al contenedor
document.querySelector('#comentario').innerHTML = resultado;
```

```html
<div id="comentario"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar backtick para incluir tu string en varias líneas.

```js
var comentario = `<p>Primer párrafo.</p>

                  <p>Segundo párrafo.</p>

                  <p>Último párrafo.</p>`;
                  
document.getElementById("contenedor").innerHTML = comentario;
```

```html
<div id="contenedor"></div>
```

Más info:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: El caracter (**`**) es *backtick*, no *backslash* (\\)

Comment: @VRoxa, llevas toda la razón, corregido, gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Podrias utilizar template string

```js
const contenedorTexto = document.getElementById('#contenedorTexto');

let texto = `este es un parrafo
            este es otro parrafo
            este tambien es otro parrafo`

    contenedorTexto.innerText = texto;
```

```html
<div id="#contenedorTexto">
</div>
```